# "Expand all menu links" Menu Block selection shows all menu items in block not just active trail items

Tags: 8, blocks, navigation, bootstrap-theme

I have a menu block that I have setup with Initial visibility level = 2 and Number of levels to display = Unlimited. When I check the "Expand all menu links" checkbox and view my menu block it is displaying ALL menu items at visibility level 2 VS the menu items in the active menu trail.

What's the be way to display only the active trail menu items without going into each menu item and setting them as "Show as expanded" individually.

I'm using Drupal 8 and a customized Bootstrap theme

Answer (score 1):

Found a patch that does the trick:
https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block/issues/2811337